# I'm getting react key error even though I haven't even rendered the component to JSX using the map function in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In the process of rendering JSX from index.jsx to root.render using Typescript, an unknown "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop." react error occurs when more than 2 divs JSX is increased.

#### index.jsx

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

const targetDom = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(targetDom as HTMLElement);

root.render(
  <div>
    <div>hello</div>
    <div>hello</div>
    // "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop." error occurs from more than 2 JSX
  </div>
);
```

#### react-app-env.d.ts

```js
/// <reference types="react" />
/// <reference types="react-dom" />
/// <reference types="react-scripts" />
```

#### tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "app"
  },
  "include": ["app"]
}
```

Why the hell am I getting these errors?
[github.com/chebread/test](https://github.com/chebread/test) is test code.

Comment: not able to recreate your issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-lena-01l1mg?file=/src/index.tsx. I recommend posting a code sandbox that shows the error

Comment: tried the same but don't get the error. did you create new project with create-react-app ?

Comment: I have created a project using Bun `bun create react test`. The explanation seems to be lacking. sorry.

Comment: https://github.com/chebread/test is the test repository.
Running `bun install` and `bun dev` will give the same result.